# What meaning does "of" have in the phrase "to see the last of someone"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

the definition of "*to see the last of someone*" from [collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/see-the-last-of-someone):

> If you see the last of someone, you do not expect to see them or deal with them again:
> **(1)** *I honestly thought I'd seen the last of you*.

As I understand, (1) means:
**(2)** *I honestly thought I'd seen you the last time*.

The use of the preposition "*of*" in "*to see the last of someone*" isn't clear to me.
What does "*of*" mean in it?
Could you show me please in a dictionary that meaning of "*of*" an example of which could be the phrase "*to see the last of someone*"?

Comment: Consider *I **see a lot of Jane** now she works in the same office as me. I thought I'd **seen the last of her** when we left school*. (And no - me seeing a lot of Jane doesn't imply she comes to work naked! :)

Comment: *Of you* here means *any part belonging to* you. Even if I saw or heard you for a little bit *again*, that would not be seeing the last of you.

Comment: "to see the last of [someone]" is an idiom, and it carries a  negative connotation that you may not be aware of. While it means you did not expect to see them again, it also implies some annoyance at their return, or that you hoped you would not see them again. Be very careful here. If you say something like this face to face with someone, it would be quite rude.

Comment: @YosefBaskin If "_of_" here means "_any part belonging to_", then after inserting it into the sentence, we have "_I honestly thought I'd seen the last **any part belonging to** you_"  –  but this is an incorrect sentence. So could you explain please what you meant?

Comment: You are right! If *of you* means *any part belonging to*, you'd have to adjust, rather than take my idea verbatim. Maybe leave out the word *any* in the substutition: "I'd seen the last **part belonging to** you."  Again, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

"To see the last of" will probably give you almost the same definition whichever English dictionary you use.
For example Merriam Webster says [to see (someone or something) for the last time](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see%20the%20last%20of%20%28someone%20or%20something%29)
The Collins Dictionary says [you do not expect to see them or deal with them again](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/see-the-last-of-someone)
Whilst the Cambridge Dictionary says [to not see something or someone again because that thing or person has gone away or has ended](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see-the-last-of)
"of" is [used to show possession, belonging, or origin](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of) and in this case it refers to the property of never meeting or interacting with the person again. It links the [non-]action to the person.

Answer (score 2):

First, (2) *...I'd seen you the last time.* doesn't always mean what you are trying to say. It could mean

*I thought I'd seen you the last time (that I was here).*

For it to mean that I thought I wouldn't see you again, it should be said

*"I thought I'd seen you **for** the last time."*

So, what other ways are there to say what you are asking about?
*When I saw you, I thought I wouldn't see you again.*

That says the same thing, but it has two clauses. A more compact expression is the one you started with,
*I thought I'd seen the last of you.*

That combines the idea that I'm talking about you, that I am referring to a previous meeting, and that then I expected not to see you again.

As a side note, the expression *the last of you* has a negative feeling, as if I'm not pleased to see you again.

Comment: It could mean 'my last sight of you'. Compare the Victorian painting of emigrants [The Last of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_of_England_(painting)).

Comment: Yes, it definitely has negative connotations. In the same league as "good bye and good  riddance"

Answer (score 0):

The specific question about the role of **of** in this construction is hard to describe.  Let's look first at a similar construction where it's easier:

> He held the bottle of rare Scotch over his glass. A single drop dripped out. Well, that's **the last of it**, he thought.

There, **of** has the function of expressing the idea of "part of a whole". And "the last" refers to the final part of the whole.

With "we've seen the last of him", we're not talking about a part of his body, like an arm or a leg, but a *sighting* of him.  The expression "seen the last of" is normally used of someone (or something), sightings of whom, or sightings of which,  have been intermittent, not regular. Moreover, these intermittent appearances are usually bothersome or bring some trouble.

For example, let's say a coyote has been turning over the rubbish bins looking for food in a suburban community, and a resident throws a few loud firecrackers towards it. The explosions give the coyote quite a scare and it runs off.  The person might say

> That was very loud!   Did you see how high he jumped! I suspect we've seen the last of that coyote.

We wouldn't use the phrase of someone beloved who has passed away from an illness, at least not without some humor being involved, perhaps to add  levity to the sad occasion. It might be a fitting remark if the person was a jokester:

> We've seen the last of Uncle Joe.

Comment: I understand that "_of_" can mean "_part of a whole_". But I cannot understand how this knowledge can help to understand what "of" means in "_to see the last of someone_". Could you please explain it?

Comment: In the phrase "the last of {x}", the nature of the *last* of **{x}** is contextual.  If it's a bottle of spirits, the last of it is the final drop or dram.  If it's a thunderstorm, the last of it might be the final peals of thunder in the distance as the storm moves off. If it's a person, it's the person's *being-here* for the final time, as the only way to "divide" presence is to approach it as intermittent, as punctuated by absences.  We won't see him *again*.